# awk nth element before last

Tags: shell, awk

I tried to get the nth element before last in UNIX shell, "nth element" is stored in a variable.

I tried awk the followings, but none of them work.

```
awk '{print $NF-$minus_day}'
awk '{print $(NF-$minus_day)}'
awk '{print $(NF-minus_day)}'
```

Comment: What is $NF and $minus_day? Could you give an example of what you have in input of awk?

Comment: @JeffT. NF is a built-in awk variable.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, what was I thinking? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly use a bash variable in `awk`, you have to pass it either with `-v`:

```
awk -v minus=$minus_day '{print $(NF-minus)}' file
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
awk '{print $(NF-minus)}' minus=$minus_day file
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For a given input file:

```
$ cat file
one 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

It would return

```
$ minus_day=3
$ awk -v minus=$minus_day '{print $(NF-minus)}' file
12

$ minus_day=4
$ awk -v minus=$minus_day '{print $(NF-minus)}' file
11
```

Comment: "have to pass" is a bit strong, as there are other options.  `awk '{print $(NF-m)}' m=$minus_day file` works quite nicely without `-v`

Comment: Fair enough, I have rewritten the sentence to make more sense. Thanks, @WilliamPursell !

Comment: You can also use double quotes in limited situations: `awk "{print \$(NF-$minus_day)}" file`.

Comment: It does work. Thank you very much for all the replies.